# jQuery drop down not appearing for autocomplete/autosuggest

Tags: jquery, dropdown, autocomplete

I have set a field to autocomplete/autosuggest but the drop down isn't appearing as I type.  I can see the admin-ajax.php requests and the data returned in the Network tab of Chrome Developer Tools so that appears to be retrieving the suggestions fine.  I'm not real sure how to troubleshoot this further, and sort the issue out.

The Javascript is as follows:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var se_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        console.log(jQuery('#body-type').suggest(se_ajax_url + '?action=se_lookup'));
    });
    </script>
```

Below is the code I've added to wordpress:

```
<?php

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'se_wp_enqueue_scripts');
function se_wp_enqueue_scripts() {
wp_enqueue_script('suggest');
}

add_action('wp_head', 'se_wp_head');
function se_wp_head() {
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var se_ajax_url = '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php'); ?>';

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        console.log(jQuery('#body-type').suggest(se_ajax_url + '?action=se_lookup'));
    });
</script>
<?php
}

add_action('wp_ajax_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_se_lookup', 'se_lookup');

function se_lookup() {
    global $wpdb;

    $search = like_escape($_REQUEST['q']);

    $query = 'SELECT DISTINCT meta_value FROM '.$wpdb->postmeta.'
        WHERE meta_value LIKE \''.$search.'%\'
        AND meta_key = \'machinery_bodyType\'
        LIMIT 5';

    foreach ($wpdb->get_results($query) as $row) {
        $value = $row->meta_value;
        echo $value."\n";
    }
    die();
}

?>
```

Comment: On your success ajax function, `console.log` your result, and look in the Console tab - this is the tab you will find any JS errors in. Are you getting the expected return?

Comment: I wrapped the jQuery in console.log and the following is what was displayed in the console: [
<input type=​"text" value=​"Tractors" name=​"body-type" id=​"body-type" size=​"9" class=​"required-field" autocomplete=​"off">​
]

Comment: So you are returning a text input in the PHP function called by your AJAX?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `.ajax()` instead of `.suggest()` in your jQuery.

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type : "post",
    url : myAjax.ajaxurl,
    data : {
        action: 'se_lookup',
    },
    success: function( result ) {
        console.log(result);
    }
});
```

You should now receive the values back from the SQL.

Comment: .suggest I believe works with a js called suggest.js

Comment: Yeah I'm not sure the point of having the extra suggest.js plugin when you don't need it though.

Comment: Regardless, within this suggest function, you will receive the proper values that the get_results query will generate.

Comment: Well the reason I asked is I wasn't sure how the code you suggested would do everything such as displaying the drop down and what not to select from.

Comment: The first issue to address it to gather the right information - you shouldn't be getting an input value with the current setup you have for your PHP function.

Comment: The matter of creating your "list" is just styling and how you work. You could create a select menu, populate that select's options and open it, or you could create a list, and when you click those items, the items "value" could be stored in an input field that is hidden (or the search box) then submit the form.